# Simple jQuery chain methods throws error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a very simple jQuery method chain that is throwing an error.  All it's supposed to do is replace the "#" with a new value ("test.html"). I'm doing this because I'm retrieving a value from a database and want to update specific links in the markup.  I have verified that the href attribute is, in fact "#".  But I'm getting an "Object doesn't support this property or method" error. I'm using jquery-1.7.1.min.js.

Can someone tell me what's wrong with this statement:

```
$('a#protoPath').attr('href').html('test.html');
```

Comment: Have a look at the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Comment: what do you mean by "replace the #" ?  In a selector that hash sign means something different to the one in an anchor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.attr('href')` returns the current attribute contents, not another jQuery object, so it can't be chained.

You need to use `.attr('href', newValue)` if you want to actually change it.

If you only want to change the one link that has `"#"` as its `href` you need to change your selector, too:

```
$('a[href="#"]')
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to set HTML content on an element attribute, try instead :

```
   $('a#protoPath').attr('href', 'test.html');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
$('a#protoPath').attr('href', 'test.html');
```